# R plot arrows instead of points

Tags: r

I have two vectors, x and y, containing the coordinates to plot. But I would like to plot, for each of them, an arrow starting from the origin to the coordinate, instead of just a point. 
Using "arrows" seems not so handy, since I should manually add the coordinate in the form

```
arrows(x0, y0, x1, y1)
```

etc...

Is there some smarter way to deal with the problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: "an arrow starting from the origin to the coordinate" - what is the origin, is it always x=0, y=0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
x <- runif(10)
y <- runif(10)
plot(x, y, type="n", xlim=c(0, max(x)), ylim=c(0, max(y)))
arrows(0, 0, x, y)
```

`arrows` can only add content to an existing plot, but cannot used not create a new plot. By first calling `plot` you set up the plot, creating axes, labels, etc., but `type="n"` tells R to hide all contents in the plot area (i.e. the points). After that you can go ahead and add the arrows.

[image]